# Workflow Manager Farm over 2 WFEs

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, workflow-manager, failover

trying again. I have a SharePoint 2013 farm with 2 WFEs, 1 SQL server, no load balancers, many 2013 and 2010 desinger workflows.

I want the workflows to keep workinf if any of the 2 WFEs dies.

How can this be achieved?

Please note that at this stage none of the WFEs are connected to a Workflow Manager Farm, as I had removed both and I am not managing to connect them back either.

Answer (score 1):

WFM requires 1, 3, or 5 servers (5 given you're running the latest CU). 2 is an invalid topology.

You need to install WFM on 3 servers and put the endpoint behind a load balancer.

Comment: to add what Trevor says the way you can achieve 3 server farm without extra servers is to put the 3rd one in the app server. I have created this kind config for my QA system which is works fine. For PROD we decided to co-host only on FE servers and we have 3 FE servers each with node of WFM. We have increased the amount of processors for PROD to 6 to keep with min requirements (4 processors for SP and 2 processors for WFM) if you use this kind of config you need to keep an eye on performance counters to ensure none of your servers is an bottleneck.

Comment: Hi Marek, my two WFEs are 2 App servers, I re-installed my workflow manager on 1 WFE and republished the workflows, however now if this server is down, workflows wont work of course. Can you elaborate on how I can achieve the 3-server farm on my 2 WFEs please?

Comment: Note that FEs shouldn't host WFM for performance reasons. WFM is a batch process thus should reside on either dedicated or backend SharePoint servers.