# Install workflow manager on 2 servers

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, workflow-manager

Anyone tried to install workflow manager farm on 2 servers!

Is it possible? Will it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As a short answer,** It's possible but **NOT** supported as well as it will **NOT** achieve High Availability!

---

The supported Workflow Manager topology consists of 1 server or 3 servers.

> Only 3 servers workflow farm topology provides High Availability and The farm with 2 or 4 servers can be built! However, it’s NOT
>   supported, and it will NOT provide High Availability.

Read more at

- [SharePoint 2016: Configure Workflow Manager](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/configure-workflow-manager-sharepoint-2016/)
- [Workflow Manager Health Checklist.](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/workflow-manager-health-checklist-in-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Mohamed El-Qassas. 2 is an invalid topology. I want to add that 5 is also supported.

It is recommended to install WFM on 1, 3, or 5 SharePoint servers. Both 2 and 4 are not valid.

Reference:
[Workflow Manager Farm over 2 WFEs](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/258721/workflow-manager-farm-over-2-wfes)